# Flask / Jinja: Error while passing list of strings

Tags: python, flask, openshift, jinja2

I am working with the following template, titled template.html, taken from https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-jinja-templating/

```
<div class="container">
    <p>My string: {{my_string}}</p>
    <p>Value from the list: {{my_list[3]}}</p>
    <p>Loop through the list:</p>
    <ul>
    {% for n in my_list %}
    <li>{{n}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Using the provided Flask view and code, the output works

```
def template_test():
    return render_template('template.html', my_string="Wheeeee!", my_list=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

I tried to modify it to use the following code, and I receive an error, and the page doesn't display

> > headerList = 
> >     ['company', 'company_text', 'contact', 'contact_links', 'contact_links_text', 'data_source', 'date_posted', 'description', 'due_date', 'phone_numbers', 'title', 'title_link', 'title_link_source', 'title_link_text']

```
def template_test():
    return render_template('template.html', my_string=headerList[0], my_list=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

I'm pretty stumped, as headerList[0] is type 'str'.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the error you receive? That would be helpful to see...

Comment: rhc tail is not showing any error unfortunately, is there a way to look at the flask error log?

Comment: Before you run the app, set `app.debug = True` and behold the power.

Comment: sberry thanks for the tip!  I currently do have the following running.
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbinit()
    application.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8888)`

Comment: You can ssh to your gear and look in the ~/app-root/logs directory for other log files.

Comment: Oh perfect!  I changed that line to 
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbinit()
    application.run(debug=True, host=os.getenv("OPENSHIFT__IP"), port=os.getenv("OPENSHIFT__PORT"))`
and it works now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If that fixed the issue for you, you should submit it as an answer and mark it as confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the initialization line from

```
if __name__ == '__main__': dbinit() application.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8888)
```

to

```
if __name__ == '__main__': dbinit() application.run(debug=True, host=os.getenv("OPENSHIFT__IP"), port=os.getenv("OPENSHIFT__PORT"))
```

and it works now. Thank you everyone